# When I run msbuild xxx.esproj, given the info "Skipping target "RunNpmInstall" because all output files are up-to-date", How shoud let it not skp?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

When I run msbuild xxx.esproj, given the info "Skipping target "RunNpmInstall" because all output files are up-to-date", How shoud let it not skp?

```
Project "D:\Code\refactor\VA\Private\UI\xxx\xxx.sln" (1) is building "D:\Code\refactor\VA\Pri
vate\UI\xxx\vxxx\xxx.esproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
RunNpmInstall:
Skipping target "RunNpmInstall" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  npm run build

  > xxx@0.1.0 build
  > env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build

  'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
D:\Code\refactor\VA\Private\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\0.5.89-alpha\Sdk\Sdk.targets(130,9): error M
SB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1. [D:\Code\refactor\VA\Private\UI\vaservice-portal\vaservice-port
al\vaservice-portal.esproj]
```

And here is my esproj file contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.89-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ShouldRunNpmInstall>true</ShouldRunNpmInstall>
    <!--Command to run on project build-->
    <BuildCommand>npm run build</BuildCommand>
    <!--Command to run on project clean-->
    <CleanCommand>npm run clean</CleanCommand>
    <StartupCommand>set PORT=1337 &amp; npm run start</StartupCommand>
    <ShouldRunNpmInstall>true</ShouldRunNpmInstall>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

From the official explaination:

```
Two common scenarios where not running npm install is desirable are:

1. When a non-npm package manager (such as yarn or pnpm) is used. In this scenario, the best solution is to create a target that runs before BeforeRestore to manually run the installation.
2. When a global package installation mechanism exists in the solution that makes running individual installations unnecessary.
```

Comment: I am looking for similar information. I want to run `npm ci` every time, not `npm install`. I can't seem to figure out how to force that.